# How do you filter mapbox layers?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, jquery

I have 6 layers that contain grid, feature, and tile layers.

```
 var layers = [{
        name: 'basemap',
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 19,
          layer: L.layerGroup([
           L.mapbox.tileLayer('wmarci.i6n42nl5'),
           L.mapbox.gridLayer('')])
      },
      {
        name: '1775',
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 19,
        layer: L.layerGroup([
          L.mapbox.tileLayer('wmarci.kcnpkffi'),
          L.mapbox.gridLayer('wmarci.kcnpkffi'),
          L.mapbox.featureLayer('wmarci.kcnpkffi')])
      },
```

How would I go about filtering those? i.e. when a checkbox is selected clear the features and vice versa.

```
<form>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="battles" value="Battles" id='filter-wars' checked>Wars
        </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" name="treaties" value="Treaties" id='filter-treaties' checked>Treaties
        </li>
      </form>
```

Can this be done with jquery or do I have to use mapbox.js?